# Unsupported 16-Bit Application when using command prompt

Tags: mysql, 64-bit, command-prompt

I've been using command prompt to connect to a host and build a database but recently I've received this message when trying to connect:

"The Program or feature "\??\c:\mysql.exe" can't start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit windows please contact a software vendor and ask if a 64-bit windows compatible version is available"

I don't understand the issue and it's worked in the past.

Comment: Have you upgraded/updated either your operating system (Windows) or MySQL lately? Something has changed, and it's most likely a recent upgrade in one of those items. (It doesn't just suddenly decide that mysql.exe is not compatible.)

Comment: No, I haven't I'm still using windows 7 could be a virus or malware causing this?

Comment: The issue you're describing is caused by a Windows issue (an actual 64-bit OS with a 16-bit app), a MySQL issue (64-bit version of MySQL on a 32-bit version of Windows), a corrupted executable, a mismatched version of components (32-bit DLLs mixed with 64-bit, or something similar). Figure out what you changed, and fix it. Did you download something that might have affected things? Do you have AV/malware detection software installed, current, and actually running? You mention you're "still running Windows 7", but did you upgrade it from 32 to 64 bit? Did you upgrade MySQL to a new version?

Comment: No, no upgrades of such have been made my OS, MYSQL or Bit Version. Although i do have several Malware software running.

Comment: *Something* has changed. mysql.exe just didn't suddenly decide to go on strike or change its executable format. You need to figure out what changed to make it stop working. We can't inspect your system from where we are to figure it out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I bet that was redirection gone wrong. Probably something like

```
mysqldump xxxx > mysql.exe xxxx
```

That `>` instead of `|` corrupted your mysql.exe file.

Check the size of the mysql.exe, and the content (with any text editor).
You're just gonna have to download it again.